# i am unable unlink my directory after using zip->download using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
[

$this->zip->download($f);
$files = glob($m .'/*.pdf', GLOB_MARK); // get all file names

       if (readfile($file)) {
            unlink($file);
         }      

]
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: no error show just zip downloaded after that directory not delete

Comment: enable error reporting, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/10464991